# Hard Modular Arithmetic Problem

Tags: number-theory

Compute $17^{-1}\pmod{83}$. Express your answer as a residue from $0$ to $82$, inclusive.

(You may find it helpful to consider the fact that $17\cdot 5=85$.)

Got it from Alcumus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$17^{-1} \equiv x \pmod{83}$$
$$17*17^{-1} \equiv 17x \pmod{83}$$
$$5*1 \equiv 5*17 = 85 \pmod{83}$$
$$5 \equiv 2x \pmod{83}$$
$$42*5 = 210 \equiv 2*42 x= 84x \equiv x \pmod{83}$$
$$44 \equiv x \pmod{83}$$

Comment: How is this a residue?

Comment: Not a quadratic residue. Its residue class $\pmod{83}$ is what is being asked for.

Comment: no 44 is what being asked for.

Comment: And what did I write down in my last line?

Comment: In the third line, I'm not sure why $5 \ast 1 \equiv 5 \ast 17 = 85 \bmod 83$ since the leftmost expression is $5 \bmod 83$ while $85$ is $2 \bmod 83$

Comment: Because $17*17^{-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{83}$.